# Working with a block/chunk splitted memory

Tags: c++, memory, chunks

I'm trying to implement garbage collector in c++ but I am having a few problems.

So I have an array of 5 elements each one with 1024 bytes in it and thats the memory that is going to be used to allocate different variables, arrays, pointers, etc. So I can't change things in it. And for that reason I made another class Chunk that has a start, size and a variable for which of the five elements its in. I also made a list of chunks which will keep all of the allocated chunks of memory.

**TASK**:With this I am trying to make a method/function in the garbage collector class to allocate a chunk of memory in the first array by finding a free spot that has enough space for the given chunk and it returns a pointer to that chunk.

The problem is that I have no idea how to work with both the sheet array and the list of chunks in order to find which space is empty and which isn't. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
class Chunk
{
    char *start;
    size_t size;
    size_t page_num;

    Chunk(); // default constructor
    Chunk(char *start, size_t size, size_t page_num); // constructor to make a chunk
}

class GC
{
    static char *sheets[5];
    static size_t chunks_count;
    static list <Chunk> chunks;

    static void init() // i initialize the sheets, sheet_count and chunks_count 
    static void* alloc(size_t size) // given size of chunk
    {
        Chunk();
        ...
    }
}
```

Note: class GC must be static and make no instances

Comment: In addition to a list of _allocated_ memory, keep a freelist of _unallocated_ memory per sheet. Whenever you allocate memory, update the freelist. When memory is freed, update the freelist again (and make sure to merge adjacent entries in the freelist)

Comment: Also, a garbage collector must keep track of which chunks are still in use (ie reachable from roots) and which are not.

Comment: @Botje so to fill it with zeros for example and then change them to ones if the memory is filled?

Comment: @Botje well Im making a simpler implementation and it doesn't detect that. It can free the chunks later.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by defining a freelist. This is a list of Chunks that are not yet allocated. For simplicity I will reuse your `Chunk` datastructure:

```
static list<Chunk> freelist;

// We need this for sorting and comparing Chunk objects.
bool operator<(const Chunk& c1, const Chunk& c2) {
  return std::tie(c1.page_num, c1.start) < std::tie(c2.page_num, c2.start);
}
```

Your `init` function should create the initial freelist entries:

```
  freelist.emplace_back(sheets[0], sheet_size, 0);
  freelist.emplace_back(sheets[1], sheet_size, 1);
  freelist.emplace_back(sheets[2], sheet_size, 2);
  freelist.emplace_back(sheets[3], sheet_size, 3);
  freelist.emplace_back(sheets[4], sheet_size, 4);
```

We establish three invariants now:

- `freelist` is always sorted by `page_num` and `start`
- `chunks` is always sorted by `page_num` and `start`
- If you interleave `chunks` and `freelist`, you should end up with the full memory range again

The `alloc` function must now find or split a chunk that is large enough:

```
static void* GC::alloc(size_t size) {
  for (auto it = freelist.begin(); it != freelist.end(); it++) {
    Chunk& c = *it;
    if (c.size < size) { continue; }
    if (c.size > size) {
      // Shrink the current free chunk 
      char *new_start = c.start + c.size - size;
      c.size -= size;
      insert_sorted(chunks, Chunk{new_start, size, c.page_num});
      return new_start;
    }
    if (c.size == size) {
      // Move the chunk from the freelist to chunks
      char *new_start = c.start;
      insert_sorted(chunks, c);
      freelist.erase(it);
      return new_start;
    }
  }
  return nullptr;
}

void insert_sorted(list<Chunk>& l, const Chunk& c) {
  auto it = std::lower_bound(l.begin(), l.end(), c);
  l.insert(it, c);
}
```

Implementing `dealloc` is now the fun part: you need to move the chunk back from `chunks` to `freelist` and then possibly merge it with the chunk before and/or after it.

Comment: Is the insert_sorted func in the class GC and also what does tie() do?

Comment: `insert_sorted` may be nested in GC, but can be a free function just as well. `tie` creates a tuple of references and is used here to create a lexicographical comparison.

Comment: I just tried your code and got a bunch of errors:
"error: ‘bool Chunk::operator<(const Chunk&, const Chunk&)’ must have exactly one argument";  "error: cannot call member function ‘void GC::insert_sorted(std::__cxx11::list<Chunk>&, const Chunk&)’ without object"; "error: ‘tie’ was not declared in this scope
    9 |  return tie(c1.page_num, c1.start) < tie(c2.page_num, c2.start);"

Comment: `operator<` must be outside of Chunk (or be a `friend`). `std::tie` lives in the `<tuple>` header. Just because you're given a solution doesn't absolve you from thinking critically

Comment: Yeah, I know I'm just kinda new to c++ and don't know all of the specifics like tuple and tie, etc so thats why I'm asking